# Thread Safe call runs slow VB.NET 2012

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, performance

I'm developing a program using VB.Net 2012. To warn you I'm very new to multi-threading. I have a class that accesses another that apparently is ran on another thread. I found the info on making a thread safe call. It's basically set up like this:

I have a windows form that is updated from another class. I set up the sub as:

```
Delegate Sub SetTextCallback([text] As String)

Public Sub set_tbxSeqNum(ByVal [text] As String)

         If Me.tbxSeqNum.InvokeRequired Then
             Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf set_tbxSeqNum)
             Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {[text]})
         Else
             Me.tbxSeqNum.Text = [text]
         End If 
End Sub
```

This is just one of many that are similar to that one. Through another class, I access it through that sub:

```
Comm_Stats.set_tbxSeqNum(SequenceNum.ToString)
```

I've searched quite a bit and I haven't come up with a clear solution. I might be left field, but as far as I can tell it's due to the threads fighting each other for control.

The problem is, after making that thread safe call, it runs terribly slow. Is there a way to link the two classes to a single thread or prevent the slow speeds? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How often are you making calls to `set_tbxSeqNum` (as in, how many times per second)?

Comment: Invoke calls are very expensive, hundreds of microseconds is not unusual.  Only update the UI at a rate that's fit for a human eye, it all turns into a blur when you do it more than once every 50 milliseconds so that's just wasted effort.  And use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke to avoid waiting for that expensive call to complete.

Comment: Unfortunately it's for transferring data for communications, so it isn't so much reliant on the human eye. At times it can make calls every second, but more often than not it makes calls about every 200 ms. This can vary. Also, there can be about 7 calls before that function is complete.

Comment: @DMC if it's not for the human eye, you should not involve any UI in it.